# Adding new objects to chrome local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

Html code:

```
<select id="server">
                <option value="kr">KR</option>
                <option selected value="euw">EUW</option>
                <option value="oce">OCE</option>
                <option value="las">LAS</option>
                <option value="ru">RU</option>
                <option value="na">NA</option>
                <option value="eune">EUNE</option>
                <option value="br">BR</option>
                <option value="lan">LAN</option>
                <option value="tr">TR</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="nickname" maxlength="16"></input></p>
<button id="save" class="flat-button">Save</button><br>
```

Javascritp code:

```
function save_options() {
  var server = document.getElementById('server').value;
  var prenickname = document.getElementById('nickname').value;

  var nickname = prenickname.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,""); //Remove html tags

  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    yourserver: server,
    yournickname: nickname
  }, function() {
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
  });
}
```

Actually when I go to save (pressing the button) into local storage obviously it overwrite my old object. I want to do that it add a new object (like an array or a list), I hope you understand what I mean. The result has to be that I can store different "server+nickname" and not only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want you'll need to use an array of objects: you will get the value of the array using `chrome.storage.sync.get`, you'll add your new server and nickname to the array, and then use `chrome.storage.sync.set` to overwrite the existing value and save it.

Your array will look like this:

```
data = [
    {yourserver: 'server1', yournickname: 'nickname1'},
    {yourserver: 'server2', yournickname: 'nickname2'},
    {yourserver: 'server3', yournickname: 'nickname3'},
    ...
];
```

Here is an example of the code:

```
// Get all the items stored in the storage
chrome.storage.sync.get(function(items) {
    if (Object.keys(items).length > 0 && items.data) {
        // The data array already exists, add to it the new server and nickname
        items.data.push({yourserver: server, yournickname: nickname});
    } else {
        // The data array doesn't exist yet, create it
        items.data = [{yourserver: server, yournickname: nickname}];
    }

    // Now save the updated items using set
    chrome.storage.sync.set(items, function() {
        console.log('Data successfully saved to the storage!');
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the big delay but working on the code I have a question, how can I print the data saved in the array of object, something like this doesn't work: 

 `"chrome.storage.sync.get(function(items) {
        document.getElementById("nicknameonpage").innerText = items.mydata.yournickname;
    });"`

This is how the object are saved: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22722558/11123123123123.PNG

Comment: @master94ga you're saving it as an array, you should use `items.mydata[0].yournickname`